# Django - Filter for Multiple Foreign Keys on the Same Table

Tags: python, django

Assume I have models like so:

```py
class Story(...):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Chapter(...):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    length = models.CharField(...)
    story = models.ForeignKey('Story', ..., related_name='chapters')
```

How can I filter for stories that have N specific chapters, i.e.:

```py
titles = ['Beginning', 'Middle', 'End']
length = 'Long'

# is there a better way to do this?
stories_with_these_chapters = Story.objects.filter(
    chapters__title = titles[0],
    chapters__length = length
).filter(
    chapters__title = titles[1],
    chapters__length = length
).filter(
    chapters__title = titles[2],
    chapters__length = length
)
```

### Edit:

So for example say I have this data:

**Stories:**

```
ID | Name
-- | ----
 1 | First Story
 2 | Second Story
 3 | Third Story
```

**Chapters:**

```
ID | Story ID | Title     | Length
-- | -------- | --------- | ------
 1 |        1 | Beginning | Long
 2 |        1 | End       | Long
 3 |        2 | Beginning | Short
 4 |        2 | Middle    | Short
 5 |        2 | End       | Short
 6 |        3 | Beginning | Long
 7 |        3 | Middle    | Long
 8 |        3 | End       | Long
```

I want to filter for stories with the Chapters titled "Beginning", "Middle", and "End" and are "Long" - which will only be Story 3 in this example because Story 1 does *not* have a chapter titled "Middle" and all of the Chapters in Story 2 are "Short".

Comment: Can you add an example without using code? i.e. with X input, I need the output to be Y

Comment: @angardi - I added an example, let me know if you need more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Ok to try to explain ways of filtering and equivalence.

If you're working with model fields or `ForeignKey` relationships:

- `.filter(A, B)` means `WHERE A AND B`
- `.filter(Q(A) & Q(B))` means `WHERE A AND B`
- `.filter(A).filter(B)` means `WHERE A AND B`

With reverse `ForeignKey` relationships:

- `.filter(A, B)` means `WHERE A AND B`
- `.filter(Q(A) & Q(B))` means `WHERE A AND B`
- `.filter(A).filter(B)` means `WHERE A AND B` *but* A and B operates on a table with duplicates, due to the multiple INNER JOINs

Having seen your edit you need to chain Q queries.

```
from functools import reduce

import operator
from django.db.models import Q

query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(chapter__title__contains=x) for x in titles))

qs = Story.objects.filter(query)
```

Putting this into the terminal to show what reduce is doing for you;

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> 
>>> import operator
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> 
>>> titles = ['Beginning', 'Middle', 'End']
>>> query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(chapter__title__contains=x) for x in titles))
>>> query
<Q: (AND: ('chapter__title__contains', 'Beginning'), ('chapter__title__contains', 'Middle'), ('chapter__title__contains', 'End'))>
```

So [`reduce`](https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/) is applying some mathematics to build a `Q` object which does an `AND` for each term in your list matching `chapter__title__contains`

***Update for addition of length column***

From the above, you can add to the `query` to add the length query;

```
>>> query.add(Q(chapter__length='Long'), query.connector)
<Q: (AND: ('chapter__title__contains', 'Beginning'), ('chapter__title__contains', 'Middle'), ('chapter__title__contains', 'End'), ('chapter__length', 'Long'))>
```

And as a side note, to see what the SQL is behind a django query you can do;

```
>>> query = User.objects.all()
>>> query.query
<django.db.models.sql.query.Query object at 0x7f910f250eb0>
>>> print(query.query)
SELECT "authentication_user"."id", "authentication_user"."password", "authentication_user"."last_login", "authentication_user"."is_superuser", "authentication_user"."email", "authentication_user"."first_name", "authentication_user"."last_name", "authentication_user"."date_joined", "authentication_user"."is_active", "authentication_user"."is_staff" FROM "authentication_user"
```

Comment: @Daniel I've seen your edit and added a potential solution

Comment: Thanks - can you explain in a bit more detail what this line is doing: `query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(chapter__title__contains=x) for x in titles)))`

Comment: @SadanA. I've added an example of what happens when building the Q query and a link to a useful article about `reduce`

Comment: Hey Mark - after some further testing this code does not work - chaining the filters together gets me the object I'm looking for but this method does not.

Comment: @Daniel have you inspected the SQL it generates to debug why it might not be working as expected?

Comment: I am not sure how to inspect the SQL - and even if I did would not be able to determine if the SQL was correct - however I am happy to provide it if it helps - otherwise I edited my question to reflect some more nuances of my problem - it seems like the "Q" object is just throwing "AND" across all my fields and not grouping them correctly.

Comment: @Daniel Oh I see. Well before you added the length column it did what you wanted. So that needs building into the Q objects. Are there any other important columns?

Comment: The Chapter object has one other column, we can call it "number_of_pages", but I don't think it adds to the complexity of the problem.

Comment: @Daniel I've added an example of adding to the `Q` query to include the `length` column and also some info on getting the SQL from a queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to write a query that does this:

1. Find all chapters matching the set of titles you are interested in
   matching the desired length.
2. Group the result by story and count the number of records per story.
3. Exclude the ones where the number of records does not match the length of the list of chapter titles.

Something like this results in an optimum query with no joins:

```
titles = ['Beginning', 'Middle', 'End']
length = 'Long'
story_ids_with_matches = Chapters.objects.order_by().values('story_id').filter(title__in=titles, length=length).annotate(chpt_cnt=Count('story_id')).filter(chpt_cnt=len(titles))
```

This will produce an output result set with "story_id" and "chpt_cnt" as fields.
You can then print details about the story by wrapping that in a query like this:

```
Story.objects.filter(id__in= [i['story_id'] for i in story_ids_with_matches])
```

To get the list of names in a single query you would have to accept having the count in the output and the query is less efficient since it does a join and also groups on a text field:

```
titles = ['Beginning', 'Middle', 'End']
length = 'Long'
story_ids_with_matches = Story.objects.order_by().values('name').filter(chapters__title__in=titles, chapters__length=length).annotate(chpt_cnt=Count('id')).filter(chpt_cnt=len(titles))
```

Answer (score -1):

You need queryset "in". For further reference please check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in).

```
stories_with_these_chapters = Story.objects.filter(chapters__title__in=["Boo", "hoo"])
```

It will fetch all the **Story** records where the **Chapter** title is either "Boo" and "hoo".

Comment: In your example - the story needs to have at least two chapters, 1 chapter with a title "Boo" and one chapter with a title "hoo" - will your solution work for this?

Comment: If your story doesn't have chapter title "hoo" it won't raise an error it will just bring the chapters that it will find from the list.

Comment: Do you see some error? May be that would help. Because I don't see any reason for this to not work based on your usecase.